# EMV: Get the CVV code from an ICC?

Tags: credit-card, emv

I'm testing an EMV card reader, and I've done the steps indicated here [here](http://www.openscdp.org/scripts/tutorial/emv/) and [here](http://blog.saush.com/2006/09/08/getting-information-from-an-emv-chip-card/) but I can't find a way to know if it's possible or not to get the Card Verification Value (CVV) code that I might need to contact the Merchant Server.

Does somebody has some links or explanation in order to get that value?

PS: I've also checked the EMV books from the [EMV Specification](http://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223) and the words CVV/CVC are not even there!

Comment: CardPeak might be easier software to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CVV is not part of the EMV standard](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_emv.pdf) (page 7).  This is just a number that is printed on the card; it's not usually present or readable from the chip itself.

You *might* be able to go digging in the "track 2 equivalent" data field and it *might* be there (as it would be on a mag-stripe), but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: This answer is correct, but just to clarify - the CVV that is on the mag-stripe (and in the track 2 equivalent data) is used as a checksum, and therefore has a different purpose to the 3 digit CVV that is embossed onto the card. The embossed CVV cannot be machine read *by design*

Comment: Yep, thanks for clarifying.  I wasn't totally sure which CVV the OP meant, so I figured I would stress that there might be something hiding in track 2 if that's what was being requested.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand the processing flow for reading EMV Card.

The real CVV is encoded during EMV data preparation with SFI tag 57 containing the track 2 data.